# What is the effect size `h` in `pwr::pwr.p.test` in `R`?

Tags: r, statistical-power, effect-size, odds

The `R` package `pwr` has a function for calculating the required sample size for a one-sample proportion test (I assume a z-test but am open to being corrected). The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/pwr.pdf) vaguely describes the `h` argument as the effect size without clarifying what, exactly, this means. I see two options.

1. Some kind of $\epsilon$ for $p_0\pm\epsilon$ as a tolerable range of being "close enough" to a null hypothesis of $p=p_0$
2. A measure on the odds scale

Is the correct answer one of these? Something else?

When I run the following line, I get a detectable effect size of `h = 1.981018`, so the additive scale does not make sense, but I am a bit surprised that the effect size might be given in odds.

`pwr::pwr.p.test(n = 2, power = 0.8)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be Cohen's $h$, defined as follows for testing a null hypothesis of $H_0: p = p_0$ with tolerance of being within $p_{\tau}$ of $p_0$.

$$
h = 2\bigg\vert
\arcsin\big(\sqrt{p_0}\big)
-
\arcsin\big(\sqrt{p_{\tau}}\big)
\bigg\vert
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $p_0+p_{\tau}$?

Comment: @Edgar Where would it be $p_0 + p_{\tau}?$ Feel free to edit. I can revert back to my original answer if I disagee.

Comment: unfortunately, i think it's not entirely easy/straightforward (see Chapter 6 in Cohen's Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences). $h$ is defined as $2|arcsin(\sqrt{p_1})-arcsin(\sqrt{p_2})|$ with $p_1>p_2$. Cohen gives a table for $h$ and a two-sided test too, which revolves around the "fixed" effect $h$, which depends heavily on the actual size of $p_1$ and $p_2$...

Comment: using this logic and staying in the notation of $p_0$ and $p_{\tau}$, one could formulate $h=2|arcsin(\sqrt{p_0+p_{\tau}})-arcsin(\sqrt{p_0-p_{\tau}})|$, but i'm not sure

Comment: @Edgar I've un-accepted the answer in hopes someone will provide a more authoritative response.